# SQL Server BCP utility not creating output file

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bcp

**Context:** A feature of one of our core applications is dependent output from a stored procedure in SQL Server. The stored procedure produces an output file using the BCP utility. I've been able to isolate the issue to the T-SQL below.

**Question:** Why is the output file `personnel_data.txt` file not being created?

```
DECLARE @bcp_cmd4 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @exe_path4 VARCHAR(200) = 
    ' cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\ & ';
SET @bcp_cmd4 =  @exe_path4 + 
    ' BCP.EXE "SELECT ''Name'', ''Title'', ''Company_Name'', ''Path'' UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT name, title, path FROM ##jsonparsed" queryout ' +
    ' "C:\mattermark_etl_project\personnel_data.txt" -T -c -q -t0x7c -r\n';
PRINT @bcp_cmd4;
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcp_cmd4,no_output;

exec xp_cmdshell 'C:\mattermark_etl_project\powershell "C:\mattermark_etl_project\open_personnel_file.ps1"',no_output
```

SQL Server outputs the following messages:
[image]

```
SQLState = S0002, NativeError = 208
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name '##jsonparsed'.
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 8180
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.
NULL

Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
NULL
Current thread 0x000037e0 (most recent call first):
NULL
```

Comment: can you share the output you see when the "PRINT" command actually prints out the contents of @bcp_cmd4? I would like to see that first, but on your end you could also try executing that printed out value on a commad line... see what you get.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the question with the message SQL Server outputs

Comment: An error occurs during the execution of `xp_cmdshell`. We cannot know what error, since you are suppressing the error message with your `no_output` clause.

Comment: AH gotcha. I disabled and found the errors that were being suppressed, posted above.

Comment: Ok I think I see what the problem is now. There's some issue with the data being populated in the global temp table so I'll investigate further, thanks.